# Getting a variable out of a nested function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a function to check if a user is already registered on a site.
However I can't figure out how to get the value of `rows` out of the function `selectEmail()`

I'm trying to store it within `temp`, but it seems to store it within its own local version of it, and I'm left with an empty variable once the query part ends.

```
function checkEmail(email, req, res){
  var temp;
  dbConnect(req,res);
  var query = 'SELECT EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL="'+email+'"';
  connection.query(query, function selectEmail(err,rows,fields){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    temp=rows;
  })
  dbClose(req,res);
  console.log(temp);
  if (temp==""){
      console.log('No matching email in database');
      return 0;
  }
  else{
      console.log('Duplicate Email detected in database');
      return 1;
  }
}
```

I've heard I'm supposed to use a callback, but I can't figure out how to get that working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that `connection.query` is asynchronous, meaning that it does not finish before the rest of the code executes.  That means that `temp` does not have a value when you reach `if(temp==""){`.

To handle this, a callback is used.  A callback is a function that is called once the code is complete, which in this case is `connection.query()`.  That is exactly what you have in this case, except not quite formatted correctly:

```
connection.query(query, function selectEmail(err,rows,fields){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    temp=rows;
})
```

Here `selectEmail()` is the callback, except that callbacks should be provided as function pointers, or anonymous functions (without a name):

```
connection.query(query, function(err,rows,fields){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    temp=rows;
});
```

This code will likely occur well after `checkEmail()` has returned.  Anything you want to happen after `conection.query()` is complete should be **in** the callback or **called by** the callback.  Like this:

```
connection.query(query, function(err,rows,fields){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    dbClose(req,res);

    if (rows==""){
        console.log('No matching email in database');
        handleEmailCheckFailure();
    }
    else{
        console.log('Duplicate Email detected in database');
        handleEmailCheckSuccess();
    }
});
```

Of course, you expect `checkEmail()` to return a value based on whether the check succeeded or not.  This will not work with an asynchronous call.  You will need to have functions to handle the passing and failing cases (`handleEmailCheckFailure`, etc above).  You also need to be aware that some time will elapse depending on the connection before either of these cases is called.